# Laravel auth filter not working on one server

Tags: laravel-4

I have a weird situation where my auth filter is being ignored on my preproduction server but not on the live and local homestead machine.

To debug I have completely reduced my two files to the absolute minimal

my not so spectacular **routes.php**

```
Route::get("/foo",['before'=>'foo',function(){return 'bar';}]);
```

here in my **filters.php** the voodoo happens

```
//die('if I uncomment this, causes the app to end here both live and local');
Route::filter("foo",function($a,$b,$c){die("this is ignored on live but not on local");});
```

going to `/foo` shows **bar**, I expected the filter to be applied and stop bar from appearing

I am completely confused as to the cause of this issue, basically right now anybody can access all pages even when not logged in.

What should I check from here on?

What I tried

- `php artisan cache:clear`
- `php artisan dump-autoload`
- `php artisan clear-compiled`
- `grep --include=\*.php -rnw . -e "filters.php"` which returned `./app/start/global.php:97:require app_path() . "/filters.php";`

Comment: Laravel has an filter reducer. Check your enviroment setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunatly my preproduction server had the environment set to `testing`

Laravel has an environment check against environments named testing
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/RoutingServiceProvider.php#L32

```
if ($app['env'] == 'testing')
{
$router->disableFilters();
}
```

I renamed the environment to preproduction to fix the issue.